# Get the user name or host name of a connecting ssh user

Tags: ssh, environment-variables

I would like to get the user name or host name of a connecting ssh user to exec some functions in the `.bashrc`.

```
# pseudo code
if (ssh && connecting_ssh_username == "foobar") {
    do something
}
```

How to get "connecting_ssh_username"?

Comment: This is a little vague, what do you mean? You want to know the username of a user logging in on a machine so that you can execute some functions in your personal .bashrc file? Please rewrite your question to be clearer.

Comment: Jep, I would like the get the user name of the logging in user from the remote computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are the administrator of the computer, you can watch the auth logs for your distribution. If you are not an administrator of the system you can use the command "w" or "users" to see who is logged in at any time, providing the administrator allows it. There is no program within Linux/BSD/Unix to do this automatically so you will probably have to script something to get this to work.

Cheers